# How to return data from cfc page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have project and I would like to use standard Javascript Ajax Call to get data from my .cfc page. Later I have worked with JQuery and now I would like to see what is a difference. So my javascript code gets triggered after user click on the dropdown (onChnage function) and I pass the argument in that function. Then I have my Ajax call and everything works well so far in this part. Now I send the method and parameter to .cfc page where is my Coldfusion function. There I defined my agrument and I have cfquery. So my question is how I can create JSON structure and return to my Javascript function where I can loop through the elements? Here is my Ajax call:

```
function myFunction(userNum){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
               var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

               for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                    alert(i);
                }

         }else{
             alert('There was an error 400');
         }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Components/myCFCpage.cfc method=getRecs&userNum="+userNum.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

So in the function above I have a question about sending url parameter. Is the best way to do that how it is in my function or that should be in xmlhttp.send() ? If so what is a difference? Also should I check for status "200" the way it is or that can be done some other way? 
Here is my cfc page:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getRecs" access="remote" returntype="JSON">
        <cfargument name="userNum" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfset cfcResults = structNew()>
        <cfset recs = StructNew()>

        <cfif arguments.userNum NEQ ''>
            <cfquery datasource="test" name="getUser">
                SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name
                FROM Users
                WHERE user_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.userNum#">
                ORDER BY last_name
            </cfquery>

            <cfset cfcResults.recordcount = getUser.recordcount>
            <cfloop query="getUser">
                <cfset recs[currentRow] = StructNew()>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].firstName = URLEncodedFormat(getUser.first_name)>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].lastName = URLEncodedFormat(getUser.last_name)>
            </cfloop>

            <cfset cfcResults.status = "200">
            <cfset cfcResults.data = recs>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset cfcResults.status = "400">
            <cfset cfcResults.message = "Error">            
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn cfcResults>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I'm wondering how I can use this data now and loop through in my javascript function? Also What is the best way to create JSON in this case?

Comment: Have tried exploring [SerializeJSON](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html)?

Comment: Yes but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Rule #1 - Do not bother calling any CFC from JS until you have first verified the function actually works in CF ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<cffunction name="getRecs" access="remote" returntype="any" returnFormat="JSON">
    <cfreturn cfcResults>
</cffunction>
```

JSON is not a valid returnType. See the [CFFunction documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html). You want `returnFormat="JSON"`.

If you have ColdFusion code and do `<cfset myVar = getRecs()/>` then the value of `myVar` will be a structure. If you do a remote call to `getRecs` ColdFusion will return the data to the remote caller in the specified return format.

No need to do anything extra or manually serialize it.

> **returnformat** - The format in which to return values to a remote caller. This
>   attribute has no effect on values returned to a local caller.
>
> The following values are valid:
>
> - **json**: serialize the return value into JSON format before returning it
>     remotely.
> - **wddx**: serialize the return value into WDDX format before returning it remotely.
> - **plain**: ensure that the return value is a type
>     that ColdFusion can convert directly to a string, and return the
>     string value without serialization. Valid types include all simple
>     types, such as numbers, and XML objects. If the return value is a
>     complex type, such as an array, or a binary value, ColdFusion
>     generates an error. If you specify a `returntype` attribute, its value
>     must be `any, boolean, date, guid, numeric, string, uuid, variablename`,
>     or `XML`; otherwise, ColdFusion generates an error. By default,
>     ColdFusion serializes all return types (including simple return
>     types), except XML, into WDDX format, and returns XML data as XML
>     text.
>
> You can also use `returnformat` as an HTTP request parameter when
>   calling a remote CFC function. This parameter has the same effect as
>   the `returnformat` attribute and overrides any `returnformat` attribute
>   value specified in the cffunction tag.

Comment: FWIW, with remote methods, you could also omit returnFormat from the function signature and instead specify the desired format via a URL parameter when invoking the function: `?returnformat=json`. 
espresso_coffee - While it is technically optional, for clarity the function signature should include a `returntype` (not the same as returnformat).

Comment: I generally like to include the type and everything so if I want to use the function locally I know what it's for, what it does etc.